# X-ray intensity and the dependence of that intensity on the atomic position

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics, scattering, fourier-transform, x-ray-crystallography

I am currently studying the textbook, *Solid-State Physics, Fluidics, and Analytical Techniques in Micro- and Nanotechnology*, by Madou. In a section on **X-Ray Intensity and Structure Factor $F(hkl)$**, the author says the following:

> From the above, the intensity of the x-ray diffraction is
>
> $$I \propto \vert F(X) \vert^2 = \left\vert \sum_{\text{all atoms}} f_j e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \right\vert^2 \tag{2.41}$$
>
> So what we measure from the x-ray film is intensity $I$, and the dependence of that intensity on the atomic position follows from the Fourier expansion of the electron density function in Equation 2.17:
>
> $$\rho(x, y, z) = \sum_{h} \sum_{k} \sum_{l} F(hkl) e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \tag{2.42}$$
>
> where $F(hkl)$ is the coefficient to be determined, and $h$, $k$, and $l$ are integers over which the series is summed. Because of the 3D periodicity, a triple summation is required:
>
> $$F(hkl) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \rho(x, y, z) e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \ dxdydz \tag{2.43}$$
>
> If we knew all the $F(hkl)$ values, we could calculate the electron density, and vice versa. Unfortunately, as remarked above, Equation 2.42 requires values of $F(hkl)$, but the measured intensities only give us $\vert F(hkl) \vert^2$. The apparent impasse is known as the *phase problem* and arises because we need to know both the amplitude and the phase of the diffracted waves to compute the inverse Fourier transform.

I have two questions relating to this.

1. How does the Fourier expansion of 2.17 lead to 2.42 (that is, what is the mathematics involved here)?
2. How do we get from 2.42 to 2.43?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify these points.

---

For the sake of clarity, I have added the relevant background information from the preceding sections of the textbook below.

In a section on **X-Ray Diffraction**, the author says the following:

> If one thinks of electron density as a mathematical function:
>
> $$\rho(x, y, z) \tag{2.17}$$
>
> With $x$, $y$, $z$ indices for real space, then the diffraction pattern is the Fourier transform of that electron density function and given as:
>
> $$F(hkl) = T[\rho(x, y, z)] \tag{2.18}$$
>
> where $F(hkl)$ is the structure factor (a scattered wave, therefore a complex number with amplitude and phase) with $hkl$ indices in reciprocal space, and $T$ is the forward Fourier transform of $\rho(x, y, z)$.

Soon after, in a section on **X-Ray Intensity and Structure Factor $F(hkl)$**, the author says the following:

> With reference to Figure 2.27, we assume two parallel plane x-ray waves of wavelength $\lambda$ and frequency $v$ (hence velocity $c = \lambda v$), scattered elastically from two nearby atoms $A$ and $B$ of identical scattering density. The wave vector for the incoming wave is $\mathbf{k}_0$ and that of the diffracted beam is $\mathbf{k}$. Because we assume elastic scattering:
>
> $$|\mathbf{k}_0| = |\mathbf{k}| = k = 2\pi/\lambda \tag{2.31}$$
>
> [image]
>
> Scattering atom $A$ is at the origin, and scattering atom $B$ is at a distance $r$ away from the origin. The path difference, or phase factor, between the waves can be calculated from Figure 2.27 as:
>
> $$p + q = \mathbf{r} \cdot (\mathbf{k} − \mathbf{k}_0) = \mathbf{r}\cdot \Delta \mathbf{k} \tag{2.32}$$
>
> The equations for the wave amplitudes are
>
> $$\Psi_A(x, t) = \dfrac{Af}{l_A}e^{i(\mathbf{k}_0 \cdot \mathbf{l}_A - \omega \cdot t)} \tag{2.33}$$
>
> and:
>
> $$\Psi_B(x, t) = \dfrac{Af}{l_B}e^{i(\mathbf{k}_0 \cdot \mathbf{l}_B - \omega \cdot t + \mathbf{r} \cdot \Delta k)} \tag{2.33}$$
>
> where $A$ is the amplitude and $f$ is the atomic scattering factor defined as the ratio of the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave scattered by atom $A$ and that of a wave scattered by a free electron. The position of the detector with respect to atom $A$ is given by $l_A$, and the position of the detector relative to atom $B$ is $l_B$. The product $\mathbf{r} \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}$ is the phase factor we calculated in equation 2.32. Generalizing, an x-ray wave scattered from the $j_{th}$ atom in a crystal is
>
> $$\Psi_j(x, t) = \dfrac{Af_j}{l_j}e^{i(\mathbf{k}_0 \cdot \mathbf{l}_j - \omega t + \mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \tag{2.35}$$
>
> where $\mathbf{r}_j$ is the position of scattered $j$ relative to scatterer $A$, and $l_j$ is the position of the detector with respect to scatterer $j$. The total scattered wave amplitude at the detector is the sum of all the contributing atoms:
>
> $$\begin{align} \Psi(x, t) &= \sum_{\text{all atoms}} \dfrac{Af_j}{l_j} e^{i(\mathbf{k}_0 \cdot \mathbf{l}_j - \omega t)}e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \\ &\cong \dfrac{A}{L} e^{i(\mathbf{k}_0 \cdot \mathbf{L} - \omega t)} \sum_{\text{all atoms}} f_j e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \end{align} \tag{2.36}$$
>
> For a small sample, the distances $l_j$ are all about the same (the crystal is small compared to the distance between it and the detector), so in Equation 2.36 we can replace $l_j$ with $L$.
>
> Constructive and destructive interference between the scattered waves that reach the detector is the result of the sum of all scattered and the scattering vector, $\Delta \mathbf{k}$, and determines where the detector should be put. The term $F(hkl)$:
>
> $$F(hkl) = \sum_{\text{all atoms}} f_je^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \tag{2.37}$$
>
> from the expression 2.36 for the wave amplitude, is the geometrical structure factor. It is defined, in analogy with the atomic scattering factor, as the ratio of the amplitude of the wave scattered by all atoms in a unit cell and that scattered by a free electron for the same incident beam. It incorporates the scattering of all atoms of the unit cell and sums up the extent to which interference of the waves scattered from atoms within the basis diminishes the intensity of the diffraction peaks. So even if the Laue condition is met, the structure factor may be zero and no diffraction will be observed. In the case that there is only one type of atom in the basis, the atomic scattering factor $f_j$ disappears ($f_j = 1$) -- identical atoms have identical scattering factors.
>
> Assume now a crystal with base vectors $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$, and $\mathbf{a}_3$ and a total number of atoms along each axis of $M$, $N$, and $P$, respectively, also accept that there is only a single atom at each lattice point (i.e., $f_j = 1$), then the amplitude of the total ave will be proportional to:
>
> $$\begin{align} \Psi(x, t) \propto F(h,k,l) &= \sum_{\text{all atoms}} e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \\ &= \sum_{m = 0}^{M - 1} \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} \sum_{p = 0}^{P - 1} e^{i[(m\mathbf{a}_1 + n \mathbf{a}_2 + p\mathbf{a}_3) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k}]} \end{align}$$

Finally, the author soon continues by saying the following:

> From the above, the intensity of the x-ray diffraction is
>
> $$I \propto \vert F(X) \vert^2 = \left\vert \sum_{\text{all atoms}} f_j e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \right\vert^2 \tag{2.41}$$
>
> So what we measure from the x-ray film is intensity $I$, and the dependence of that intensity on the atomic position follows from the Fourier expansion of the electron density function in Equation 2.17:
>
> $$\rho(x, y, z) = \sum_{h} \sum_{k} \sum_{l} F(hkl) e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \tag{2.42}$$
>
> where $F(hkl)$ is the coefficient to be determined, and $h$, $k$, and $l$ are integers over which the series is summed. Because of the 3D periodicity, a triple summation is required:
>
> $$F(hkl) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \rho(x, y, z) e^{i(\mathbf{r}_j \cdot \Delta \mathbf{k})} \ dxdydz \tag{2.43}$$
>
> If we knew all the $F(hkl)$ values, we could calculate the electron density, and vice versa. Unfortunately, as remarked above, Equation 2.42 requires values of $F(hkl)$, but the measured intensities only give us $\vert F(hkl) \vert^2$. The apparent impasse is known as the *phase problem* and arises because we need to know both the amplitude and the phase of the diffracted waves to compute the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: I think (2.42) is an inverse Fourier transform to obtain ρ from F. I would add a minus sign in (2.42) if I were the author. If we add the minus sign, (2.42) and (2.43)  will resemble Fourier/inverse Fourier transform relation, but I don't know why the author sets (2.42) discrete and (2.43) continuous (and why the interval of integration is [0,1]).

Comment: As far as I know, the fundamental equation is F(Q)=∫ρ(r)exp(-Qr)dr ; ρ(Q)=∫F(Q)exp(Qr)dQ where r is space vector  and Q is reciprocal space vector.

Comment: @NoNames Do you have any references for this?

Comment: Structure Analysis by Small-Angle X-Ray and Neutron Scattering,Dmitri I. Svergun L.A. Feigin, page 7. I forgot 2πi in the exponent. F(Q)=∫ρ(r)exp(-2πiQr)dr ; ρ(Q)=∫F(Q)exp(2πi Qr)dQ. Q is equivalent to Δk in your post.

Comment: Given the information provided by @NoNames , I think the question now becomes, as was stated: Why is 2.42 discrete and 2.43 continuous, and why is the interval of integration $[0, 1]$?

Comment: As to why the interval of integration is $[0, 1]$, I think it is because we are dealing with **unit** cells, as alluded to here: "*It is defined, in analogy with the atomic scattering factor, as the ratio of the amplitude of the wave scattered by all atoms in a unit cell and that scattered by a free electron for the same incident beam. It incorporates the scattering of all atoms of the unit cell and sums up the extent to which interference of the waves scattered from atoms within the basis diminishes the intensity of the diffraction peaks.*"

Comment: The book, in my opinion, is a hodgepodge. I think there are books elaborating on this topic better. If you want to study TEM, this might be a good choice.Transmission Electron Microscopy and Diffractometry of Materials - B. Futz, J. Howe. chapter 5 or 6, Diffraction from Crystals

Comment: @NoNames I’m interested in MEMS and NEMS; that’s what the primary purpose of the textbooks is. The reason it’s such a hodgepodge is because it aims to teach the necessary background material as well (such as solid-state physics, in those case). In the meantime, I started studying *Introduction to Solid State Physics* by Kittel, which is a well-regarded solid state physics textbook.

Comment: And, of course, MEMS and NEMS are a hodgepodge of different application areas anyway, so that’s expected.